# Feudalism vs Serfdom

Tags: russia, peter-i-russia

Are these two the same? I was thinking that Serfdom will always exist on your feudalism but not vice versa. For example Peter the Great of Russia employed serfdom however these service were not part of the feudal structure because it was an absolute rule. Am I correct what do you guys think?

Comment: You are correct. And Russia is a good example. But of course one can start a long and useless discussion about definitions of serfdom and feudalism.

Comment: Suggest you consult the definitions of the relevant terms; the answer is relatively clear.  Serfdom is the bottom of a feudal structure where an individual is bound to the land and functionally owned by his feudal lord. Feudalism is an economic and governance structure in which loyalty and military service is exchanged for protection and benefit. The two terms have the same relationship as "citizen" and "republic".

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace but look at my example of Russia. Peter was an absolute ruler but he still had serfdom. there were no lords and vassals or nights or local rulers.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Russian history, but I think you'll find there were bucket loads of nobility.  Nobility coming out his ears; Boyars and Counts and Archdukes .  [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_nobility) has tables of them

Comment: I think you're confused by the definition of "absolute" rule - another example, the French Kings declared themselves "absolute monarchs" - but they still had a bunch of lords and other nobility governing at the more local level. Absolute rule is not the same as direct rule.

Comment: So does that mean the French govt structure was feudal? in my opinion I don't think it is King Louis the 14th had full command over everyone and even forced the nobles to move to Versailles. There wasn't this "local level" style rule. also the serfs were bound to the land but didn't necessarily provide for their "lords". they had to pay taxes to the king @HorusKol

Comment: @Mark C Wallace: There is a substantial difference between Russia and France. Since Ivan III, the tsar considered everyone, including boyars, his slaves. And history of Ivan VI and later tsars shpows that this was indeed the case.

Comment: I'm not sure I compared France and Russia - I quoted a wikipedia page that referenced a list of Russian Imperial titles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic; the question is generating discussion about the definition of the terms, rather than answers.  Please revise the question to define the terms and refine the question.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not the same.  Feudalism describes a kind of relation of lords to kings, Serfdom a relation of the tillers of the land to their lords.  Consult a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Serfdom and feudalism aren't the same, but they are related.

Feudalism is a system of land grants given by kings to high nobles, subdivided by these nobles to petty nobles, subdivided by petty nobles to large "gentleman" farmers, etc. thereby creating a landed hierarchy.

What makes feudalism work is serfdom, that is, tying peasants to the land on which they were born and work on. If peasants were free to come and go, land would lose much of its value, thereby undermining feudalism.

Comment: but can serfdom exist separately without needing the rest of the feudal structure

Comment: @yasgur99: In theory, yes, if there are no "intervening" nobles, and everyone was a peasant reporting directly to the king. But only someone like Peter the Great would consider such a system. Most kings prefer to "delegate" part of their rule to nobles.